# TokenRegex rule excluding the tokens that were caught by any other rule

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am using stanford nlp tokenRegex to tokenize. I am using a regex file. Following are the rules i have used.

**`Rule 1`** :

```
 {
   ruleType:"tokens",
   pattern:([{tag:/NN/}|{tag:/NNP/}]),
   result:"Single noun"
}
```

**`Rule 2`**

```
{
   ruleType:  "tokens",
   pattern:([{tag:/NN.*/}|{tag:/CD*/}]),
   result : "Noun with Number"
}
```

The sentence I have given is `Take note with the Samsung Notebook 9 Pen` and i got the following results

note -> Single noun

Samsung Notebook 9 Pen -> Noun with Number

Even though the POS for samsung,notebook,pen... is `NN` it is excluded.
It is not caught by `rule1`, ie the words caught by `rule 2` is excluded by `rule 1`.

Is there any way to match both rules?